# machine learning model to segregate input data

Tags: machine-learning

Consider these references as **EXAMPLES** :

> 1)Cahn, R. S.; Ingold, C.; Prelog, V. Specification of Molecular Chirality. Angew. Chem. Int. Ed. 1966, 5, 385-415.
>   
> 2)Christie, G. H.; Kenner, J. The Molecular Configurations of Polynuclear Aromatic Compounds. J. Chem. Soc., Trans. 1922, 121, 614-620.
>   
> 3)Kuhn, R. Molekulare Asymmetrie in Stereochemie, 1933, 803.
>   
> 4)Oki, M. Recent Advances in Atropisomerism. Topics in Stereochemistry 1983, 14, 1-81.
>   
> 5)Miyashita, A.; Yasuda, A.; Takaya, H.; Toriumi, K.; Ito, T.; Souchi, T.; Noyori, R. Synthesis of 2,2'-bis(diphenylphosphino)-1,1'-binaphthyl (BINAP), an atropisomeric chiral bis(triaryl)phosphine, and its 
>   use in the rhodium(I)-catalyzed asymmetric hydrogenation of α-(acylamino)acrylic acids. J. Am. Chem. 
>   Soc. 1980, 102, 7932-7934.

I have a large number of references ( like mentioned above ), and I want to segregate data from each of those references ( five for this case ) into separate parts such as

1) Name of the author(s),

2) Title of the topic

3) Date/year of publication

4) Pages and

5) Any other information

I want to create a machine learning model which should be capable of learning the formats by itself and get the right meaning/data from the references in to separate parts.The algorithm should be as much efficient as possible.

**Question :**

- What algorithm and what approach should I have to use to implement the above functionality?
- Would I be required to use multiple algorithms to create a model for the above scenario?

Comment: this definition is too broad with respect to StackOverflo policy of MCVE-based questions. Kindly read more about this Community Do-s and Don't-s. **For the problem, per se, your problem formulation does not need a Machine Learning at all, by-definition scientific papers citations have binding syntax rules and a lexer-based approach to parse these would be just-enough to process the task.**

Comment: I don't want to use any parsing approach.I want my model to be capable of finding different formats by itself, and intelligently segregate the data in to individual parts.

Comment: Why have you deleted a part of [examples]?

Comment: You may want to read **whathaveyoutried.com** & show some respect to the StackOverflow Community, which strongly encourages to post high quality questions, altogether with an MCVE ( a **M**inimum-**C**omplete-**V**erifiable-**E**xample of code ) showing what-you-have-tried so far. You may want to update your post, so as to meet this minimum reasonable level of quality & to show your will to respect other StackOverflow contributing members. They are professionals who love to answer good questions on MCVE-related issues. **Enjoy being StackOverflow Member & do support this Community Netiquette**

Comment: Sorry.I'm new to stack overflow. Since you commented about my question as being too broad, i thought that maybe i can reduce the number of examples to make it short. Besides, the number of examples doesn't matter, as i only wanted to show how  diverse the references will be.Also i'll consider reading the guidelines which you suggested.

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions on different sites in the Stack Exchange network. This has also been posted at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/309932/6384